# stringstream sgetn returns NULL on iOS 5.1

Tags: c++, ios, llvm, objective-c++

i have a code that copies contents of `std::stringstream` to `char * dest`

```
    static size_t copyStreamData(std::stringstream & ss, char * const & source, char * dest)
    {
        ss.str("");
        ss.clear();
        ss << source;
        size_t ret = ss.rdbuf()->sgetn( dest, (std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max)() ) ;
        dest[ret] = 0;
        return ret;
    }
```

on iOS 5.0 and below it works fine as expected... But in iOS 5.1 it returns NULL.

What am i doing wrong? also How can i patch my code ?

Comment: It this code just supposed to copy the string then return how many characters it used, also why doesn't it construct it's own string stream, if it is supposed to do what I said then there are much easier ways of doing it.

Comment: i did make copy but, i want to find out the reason why this is not working...

Comment: @Alkimake: actually, you are not copying the content of the `std::stringstream` (at least its content from outside the function). For some weird reason you are copying the content from `source` to the `ss` and then from `ss` to `dest`. What's the role of `ss` here ?

Comment: i realized that lately, there was no need to create a `std:stringstream` at first place. i just want to know why it is not functioning any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should choose your string representation.

If you have to use C-strings, for some reasons, then your function is called [`strncpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strncpy/).

```
std::strncpy(dest, source, max_size_of_dest);
```

Read about the caveats in the link.

If you can use a better abstraction, however, then you are encouraged to move to `std::string`.

```
void copy(std::string const& source, std::string& dest) { dest = source; }
```

Not having to deal with buffer length (and thus not messing up more often than not) is a very powerful help.

Note that nothing prevents you from manipulating `std::string` within your application and still communicating with C methods: `.c_str()` helps a lot.

Comment: @Alkimake: It must be a weird conversion from `size_t`. The issue is that `size_t` is unsigned while `streamsize` is allowed to be signed. For maximum portability you would have to use `(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max)()`.

Answer (score 2):

What you're trying to do is basically the same as doing:

```
std::size_t length = std::strlen(source) + 1; // + 1 for '\0'
std::copy(source, source + length, dest);
// Assuming dest has length + 1 bytes allocated for it
```

I doubt `sgetn` is returning NULL, as `sgetn` returns `std::streamsize` and not a pointer type.  Is it returning 0, or is another function returning NULL?  Have you tried flushing the stream before calling `rdbuf()`?

Comment: I think they mean dest was getting set to null? IDK, any this is a much better alternative than using sstreams for buffers. Although you should see if you can use std::string instead.

Comment: Questions to the OP are for comments, this is not a forum (yeah, it's hard to get it at first...)

Comment: I assume by "you" you mean Alkimake. `std::string` is indeed a much better alternative if he can use it, I will agree.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Thanks for letting me know; I figured since I was posting a code block I'd ask the questions along with it.  I'll separate them next time.

Comment: This code comes from an iOS application so i have a char*. I simply dont want to convert between those.